# Textbox com edição

Tags: html, textbox, edittext

Eu tenho uma ***textbox*** e queria poder fazer edição no texto que nela está.
Por exemplo, queria que no site pudesse escrever na textbox o seguinte texto:

"Isto é um teste!"

E que pudesse fazer, ao clicar em botões, por exemplo, a seguinte edição:

"**Isto** *é* um ***teste***"

Eu já tentei pesquisar mas só me aparecia coisas como fazer com que a textbox não permita escrever e assim...
Mas nada daquilo que quero.

Alguém sabe alguma coisa sobre isto ou mesmo um site que eu possa ir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você esteja procurando um Rich Text Editor para HTML. Dê uma olhada no [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), por exemplo.